# Access field using string?

Tags: string, actionscript-3, dynamic, field

I have `ArrayCollection` of strings with field names.

I would like to access object properties dynamically.

```
var myObject:MyObjectType = new MyObjectType();
var fields:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(["f1", "f2", "f3"] );
for (var index:int = 0; index < (event.result as ArrayCollection).length; index++ ) {
    myObject.[fields[index].toString()] = event.result[index];
}
```

How  could I do tat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace the line inside the for loop by the following:

```
myObject[fields[index].toString()] = event.result[index];
//      ^
// Remove the dot
```

Also, note that`fields` contains strings, so you can remove the `.toString()` part:

```
myObject[fields[index]] = event.result[index];
```